# Polymorphism and database loading in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, oop, polymorphism

I've got a problem loading records into a database in a polymorphic manner.

I have:

- a '`Record`' object extended by the different types of record (`RecordA`, `RecordB`)
- a method `load_record()` which doesn't know what type of record it is loading
- a database interface, which needs to contain all the information about the database

As I understand it, polymorphically I could do:

```
class RecordA(Record):
    def load_into_db(self, db_impl):
        db_impl.load_record_a(self)


class DbImpl(DbInt):
    def load_record_a(self, record):
        ... 
    def load_record_b(self, record):
        ... 

def load_record(record):
    record.load_into_db(db_impl)
```

or

```
class RecordA(Record):
    def get_record_data(self):
        ....
    def get_db_proc(self, db_impl):
        return db_impl.get_record_a_proc()


class DbImpl(DbInt):
    def get_record_a_proc(self):
        ...

def load_record(record):
    record_data = record.get_data()
    db_proc = record.get_db_proc(db_impl)
    db_impl.load_record(record_data, db_proc)
```

These both seem a bit clunky.  Alternatively, we could effectively use a switch statement:

```
class DbImpl(DbInt):
    procs = { RecordA: ..., RecordB: ...}
    ...

def load_record(record):
    data = record.get_data()
    db_proc = procs[type(record)]
    db_impl.load_record(record_data, db_proc)
```

As is probably obvious by now, the problem is that the database needs to use a specific stored procedure (which it has in its own code) but it doesn't know which one to use without asking the record itself.

Example 1 looks most polymorphic to me, but it still requires editing the `DbImpl` code whenever we add a new type of record, so is it better than example 3?  And if so, why?

Cheers,
Will

Answer (score 1):

What makes the most sense to me is to have a base class that holds the basic database functionality, such as putting something into the database and the connection info. From this base class you will then subclass the RecordA, RecordB, RecordC, ... Which will hold the information/functionality such as the stored procedure information.  Having a base class with a bunch of methods feels clunky and does not fit into the OOP paradigm in my opinion.

So, Base class with basic database functionality then each Record subclass will contain the required information for that specific record type.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of doing it like this.  I intended the database class to be subclassed / implemented for different types of database (Oracle, MySQL).

Comment: Ah, in that case I would come up with a common interface between your varying components so as to make it transparent to the subclasses, although this may not work into your stored procedures completely, but if done properly would require much less code overhead.

Answer (score 0):

In this case if the Record type relates to a particular stored procedure, then I would say the record itself need to understand what stored procedure need to be run and pass that data to the DB class where it is implement.  Thus the DB class would not need to be modified with each new record type. The recordType would just need to be coded to understand the stored procedure name that needs to be used and expose that name to the DB class.

Comment: This would raise a problem if we have to make different stored procedures for different implementations of the database class (we do, in fact).  I'm reluctant to put database-specific information in the record class.

Comment: Regardless you still have to write the new functionality and instead of in a class you are moving it to the database class which pulls away from and OOP design.

Comment: @sean Was this a response to wilbo or me?  To me, you would want to leave the DB class intact and not add cases there for each different record type.  So you put the knowledge of which stored procedure to use with the record class, but the DB class is needed to actually implement it.  Either that our you you have a number of DB subclasses for each stored procedure and have a factory class the record uses to get the one it needs.

Comment: To wilbo. What you have said is what I would try to implement as it makes more sense to pull out the procedures and put them into the sub classes than to implement a bunch of methods in the DB class. The DB class should have the underlying backend code to communicate and execute the procedure this way the subclasses can just get the job done without that overhead or copying multiple copies of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue and have found the existing database ORMs lacking as far as polymorphism/OOP is concerned, and to that end I have been working on a new one focusing primarily on that.  Its called ORB and can be found at: http://docs.projexsoftware.com/api/orb/

Right now it only works with PostgreSQL and Mongo, but I'll be extending it to more backends soon.

Its very flexible depending on what you're trying to do, whether its something simple like:

- Base class (database layer)
- Subclasses (pure python calls - so controller logic running of the same table)

or

- Base class (abstract layer - common controller logic, no tables defined)
- Subclasses (database layer - each define different database tables)

or

- Base class (database layer - defines root table)
- Subclasses (database layers - defines inherited table, for Db's that support it, or duplicate columned tables for those that don't)

Here's an example:

```
# import the orb system
from orb import Table, Column, ColumnType, Orb

# define the base class (will create default_fruit table)
class Fruit(Table):
    __db_columns__ = [
        Column(ColumnType.String, 'shape'),
        Column(ColumnType.String, 'color'),
        Column(ColumnType.String, 'name'),
        Column(ColumnType.String, 'classType')
    ]

    def initRecord( self ):
        """
        Set the initialization information from the base Table type
        """
        super(Fruit, self).initRecord()
        self.setRecordDefault('classType', self.__class__.__name__)

    @staticmethod
    def expanded( records ):
        """
        Expands the records based on their class type.

        :return   [<Table>, ..]
        """
        out = []
        for record in records:
            # map the record to their base classes
            model = Orb.instance().model(record.classType())
            if ( not model ):
                out.append(record)
                continue

            expanded_record = model(record)
            if ( not expanded_record.isRecord() ):
                continue

            out.append(expanded_record)
        return out        

# define the sub class (no database table)
class Apple(Fruit):
    def initRecord( self ):
        super(Apple, self).initRecord()
        self.setRecordDefault('shape', 'round')
        self.setRecordDefault('color', 'red')

# define the sub class (with a sub-table, will create default_banana table)
class Banana(Fruit):
    __db_columns__ = [
        Column(ColumnType.String, 'isPlantain')
    ]

    def initRecord( self ):
        super(Banana, self).initRecord()
        self.setRecordDefault('shape', 'oblong')
        self.setRecordDefault('color', 'yellow')
```

That would define 3 different classes (Fruit, Apple, Banana), and 2 database tables (default_fruit, default_banana)

Using this system (you'd have to created database connections, etc. as defined in the docs) would give you something like:

```
>>> from fruits import Fruit, Apple, Banana
>>> apple = Apple()
>>> apple.setColor('green')
>>> apple.setName('Granny Smith')
>>> apple.commit()
>>> banana = Banana()
>>> banana.setName('Chiquita')
>>> banana.setPlantain(False)
>>> banana.commit()
>>> fruits = Fruit.select() # select all fruit
[<Fruit>, <Fruit>]
>>> fruits = Fruit.expanded(fruits) # expand the fruit based on their types
[<Apple>, <Banana>]
```